# AIR: How to customize badge.swf to launch native installer app (.exe)

Tags: flash, air, flash-builder

I'm trying to follow this page to launch my AIR native installer application from the browser using "browser invocation"

- http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=distributing_apps_3.html#1036176

I've loaded the 'badge' sample app into a new "Flex Project (Web)", and made the appropriate changes to the 'AIRBadge.as' file. But I can't seem to use FlashBuilder 4.5 to compile a new 'badge.swf' file which includes my changes.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

i'm using this one for badges:

http://knomedia.com/air/badgeBuilder/

Comment: That's an awesome badge builder, but I don't think it works for installing/launching ".exe" apps.  What I really want is to have a badge that will _launch_ an installed app using browser invocation. any thoughts?

Comment: this works nice for an air application installer to launch from a browser. what do you mean by saying ".exe" apps?

Comment: I have an AIR app that is built as a "native application" with access to the local command shell. It is a .exe file, NOT a .app file and cannot be installed from a badge. However, once installed, I'd like to launch it from a badge with extra params for username and uid.  see: http://192.150.8.118/devnet/air/ajax/articles/interacting_with_native_process.html